# Dropping column from one dataframe based on column value of second dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes df1 and df2, both consisting of 8 columns each as seen below :

```
**df1**
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║John ║ Mark ║ Jane ║ Natasha ║ Oliver ║ Tony ║ Judd ║ Ron ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝


**df2**
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║True ║True ║False ║True ║False ║False ║False ║True║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

**df1** has columns that are names of different people while **df2** has column names that are boolean values. What I want to do is drop all columns in **df1** that have a corresponding value of **False** in **df2**. So the resulting output should look like this :

```
**output**
╔════════════════════════════╗
║John ║ Mark ║ Natasha ║ Ron ║
╚════════════════════════════╝
```

I am reading both the dataframes from csv files.

Any and all help would be appreciated.

**Note** : The actual dataframes have 500 columns each. Used 8 as an example for visualization purposes as well as to show that the dataframes have equal number of columns

Thanks in advance

Comment: It seems an odd way to set up and transform your dataset. I'd rename df2 to have the same headers as df1 with the boolean values as the first row. Then you could easily pd.concat both dataframes and select columns based on the last row of the new df.

Comment: Renaming 500 boolean values to 500 unique different names would be cumbersome to say the least. Hence I am trying this approach

Comment: not really. If they are in the same order:  `df1head = list(df1)` `df2head = list(df2)` to get both header names, then `df2.rename(columns = (dict(zip(df2head,df1head)),inplace = True)`

Comment: does df1 have any data under the header names? Or are both df's only headers? If they are both only headers, transpose them and join on index, then select by the boolean value.

Comment: df1 has data under header. It is salary for each day. df1 has 19164 rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, using basic indexing.  However, when you parse your `df2`, the column names have duplicates and are altered, so  it requires a bit of cleaning.

***Setup***

```
names = ['John', 'Mark', 'Jane', 'Natasha', 'Oliver', 'Tony', 'Judd', 'Ron']
cols = ['TRUE', 'TRUE.1', 'FALSE', 'FALSE.1', 'TRUE.2', 'FALSE.2', 'FALSE.3', 'TRUE.3']

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=names)
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=cols)
```

---

```
df1.loc[:, df2.columns.str.contains('TRUE')]
```

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [John, Mark, Oliver, Ron]
Index: []
```

Comment: I am reading the dataframes from csv files so when I try this method I the KeyError : "None of the [Index('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8',.......'499' are in [columns]. Also both the dataframes have 500 columns not 8. I used 8 as an example for simplicity and convenience.

Comment: Then you haven't accurately represented your data.  I'm guessing your columns aren't boolean, but `str`, in which case you need to convert to `bool`

Comment: Post edited to give more accurate description of problem. I apologize for the misleading post

Comment: @SteviG try indexing with `df1.loc[:, (df2.columns == 'True')]`

Comment: That gives an 0 columns

Comment: Then again, it's difficult to answer your question.  Please provide the output of `df1.columns[:5]` and `df2.columns[:5]`

Comment: df 1 : John, Mark,Jane,Natasha,Oliver and df2 : True,True,False,True,False

Comment: It's impossible for me to determine datatypes from that, please put the *actual* output **including the datatype** in your question

Comment: df2:Index(['TRUE', 'TRUE.1', 'FALSE', 'FALSE.1', 'TRUE.2', 'FALSE.2', 'FALSE.3',
       'TRUE.3', 'FALSE.4', 'TRUE.4',
       ...
       'FALSE.243', 'FALSE.244', 'FALSE.245', 'FALSE.246', 'FALSE.247',
       'FALSE.248', 'FALSE.249', 'TRUE.247', 'TRUE.248', 'TRUE.249'],
      dtype='object', length=500) and df1 : df1 : 'John','Mark','Jane','Natasha','Oliver'  dtype='object', length=500)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183978/discussion-between-stevi-g-and-user3483203).